# Find the volume of the tetrahedron by vector analysis

Tags: vector-analysis

Find the volume of the tetrahedron bounded by the coordinate planes and the plane x+y+z=1 by vector analysis.

I couldn't solve it, please help me.

Comment: Maybe you can write what you tried so users can help

Comment: i tried to apply (1/6)*a*(bxc) but i'm not sure if i should take points on xyz plane, or there is another way to solve it

Comment: Can you picture the situation being described here visually? You have a tetrahedron which lies entirely in the first octet (x,y,z all non-negative).

Comment: I took 3 points A(0,1,0),B(1,0,0)and C(0,0,1), after joining them i got three edges of tetrahedron and tried to apply the volume law for tetrahedron.Is it okay?